# DynamoDB Exception - Supplied AttributeValue has more than one datatypes set

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying a batchwrite in DynamoDB but it fails.

```
TableName -  td_notes_learn
PK user_id - String
SK datetime - Number
```

My attempt:

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
AWS.config.update({ region: "us-east-1" });

const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

docClient.batchWrite(
  {
    RequestItems: {
      td_notes_learn: [
        {
          DeleteRequest: {
            Key: {
              user_id: "D",
              datetime: 5
            }
          },
          PutRequest: {
            Item: {
              user_id: "G",
              datetime: 5,
              content: "HELLO WORLD"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error found" + err);
    } else {
      console.log(data);
    }
  }
);
```

Exception :

> Error foundValidationException: Supplied AttributeValue has more than
> one datatypes set, must contain exactly one of the supported datatypes

Also, in the same code, if I run the `DeleterRequest` and `PutRequest` request individually by commenting the other one, the code works fine, error only occurs if I run the together.

Comment: same problem, same udacity course ^^

Answer (score 7):

Looks like all the requests needs to be a separate json object and the issue in my code was that all requests was in one json object. Below is the working code.

```
docClient.batchWrite(
  {
    RequestItems: {
      td_notes_learn: [
        {
          DeleteRequest: {
            Key: {
              user_id: "D",
              datetime: 5
            }
          }
        }, // WAS MISSING
        {  // WAS MISSING
          PutRequest: {
            Item: {
              user_id: "G",
              datetime: 5,
              content: "HELLO WORLD"
            }
          }
        } // WAS MISSING
      ]
    }
  },
  (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error found" + err);
    } else {
      console.log(data);
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: Thank you! I was having an issue and just being able to see an example of a correct request was very useful. If only that could be include in the AWS documentation.